# How can I get R to autoload my .r file after edit it?

Tags: r, rstudio

Say I have made a function "function.r", after editing the function I have to reload into my global environment via source('function.r'). Is there anyway I can get around having to reloading it into my global environment every time I make an edit?

I'm looking for the same functionality as .m files in Matlab, where when I call the function/script it executes the .m file as opposed calling a preloaded function.

I'm using R studio, if that makes any difference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Source on save option. Just check the check box above your code.

[image: source on save in RStudio]